# How to make unmovable Splitter of the SplitterContainerControl DevExpress?

Tags: devexpress, splitter

I've been using SplitterContainerControl of DevExpress, and i'm not finding a way to make the splitter unmovable. Already googled, no relevant results found.
Any one knows anything about this? please share

Comment: Why do you need to make the splitter fixed?  Wouldn't it be better to just use two separate panels at this point?

Comment: yeah, that's a good point that i don't know why in earth i didn't think of.!!! damn

Comment: so ashamed to have even asked about it :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

uh...a splitter that won't move is just a panel!